# An error occurred [No such property: messageExchange for class: Script8], see error log for details

Tags: java, groovy

I have code:

```
context.FullRequest.updateAndRunFullRequest(user, contactInDb)
    def groovyUtils =new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context) 
    def requsetHolder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder(messageExchange.requestContent )
    if (checkTestStepStatus("FullRequest") == 'true')
            fullRequestData = context.FullRequest.assertFullRequest()
    else
    {
                   def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)
        def holder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder(messageExchange.responseContent) 
            context.QuickRequest.logWarnText("Error")
            assert 1 == 2
    }
```

While I try to execute my code I have got:

```
Tue Sep 08 20:40:43 MSK 2015:ERROR:groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: messageExchange for class: Script1
   groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: messageExchange for class: Script1
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoGetPropertySite.getProperty(PogoGetPropertySite.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGroovyObjectGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:231)
    at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:59)
    at com.eviware.soapui.support.scripting.groovy.SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.run(SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.java:92)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.WsdlGroovyScriptTestStep.run(WsdlGroovyScriptTestStep.java:141)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.panels.teststeps.GroovyScriptStepDesktopPanel$RunAction$1.run(GroovyScriptStepDesktopPanel.java:250)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Please help me to solve the problem. 
Where I can take messageExchange from??? Or How I will define it right

Comment: `messageExchange` want to be resolved (ln 3) as property (probably is unknown in other way) in Your script (and script is by auto Script1 class). BTW I never use big groovy algorithms in 'script' mode, only in "object" mode. What You have in wider code?

Comment: I have some scripts:
ScriptOne
ScriptTwo
ScriptTree
Main Srcirp which runs all this script by order
How can I get responce from SoupUI and log it out&?? I need only responce

Answer (score 0):

Are you running this as a Groovy step ? then it will not work.

**Groovy** does not have **messageExchange** variable available. You may need to put your code into **Script Assertion**

The reason why **messageExchange** is only available to script assertion because the step has request and response attached to it.

Groovy step does not have any request or response attached to it